# SharePoint Web App extension, AAM configuration (and AD FS authentication)

Tags: claims-based-auth, alternate-access-mapping, adfs, extended

I have a SharePoint web application configured with the following URL: http://test:1162

I have extetended the web app to the Intranet zone with the following site name:
http://mysiteaddress with ADFS authentication.

I have then created the following AAM:

```
http://test:1162      Default   http://test:1162 

http://mysiteaddress  Intranet  http://mysiteaddress

https://mysiteaddress Intranet  http://mysiteaddress
```

I have configured a Relaying Party on AD FS using as identifier the https address. Now I manage from the Web App in http to request the autentication but once I enter my credentials in the adfs form I get a Server Error '/' Runtime page on the address "https://mysiteaddress/_trust. In the ULS logs I get a lot of error concerning the AAM misconfigured and URI of the sites not found:

> Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services
>   are accessing the site http://test:1162 with the URL
>   https://mysiteaddress.  This may cause incorrect links to be
>   stored or returned to users.

I have some confusion around the AAM configuration and AD FS on a web app extension, anyone see some macroscopic mistake in here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why you have this error. Maybe you should check in IIS whether the SSL mapping is correct (when you add AAM in Sharepoint, IIS is not configured automatically).

However with SAML claims (ADFS) authentication, you have HTTPS all over the place. So I would configure the Intranet extension with SSL as default:

```
https://mysiteaddress Intranet  https://mysiteaddress

http://mysiteaddress  Intranet  https://mysiteaddress
```

Here HTTPS is the normal way of accessing your website, and you have an additional HTTP endpoint in case "something" is accessing your website using HTTP (typically, you have a reverse proxy somewhere that does SSL offloading).